# How to Trim a Line From An Ellipse (AutoCAD 2014)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, line, trim, autocad

### Goal

To trim a line in an ellipse that goes to it's center. The portion of the line that enters the ellipse should be trimmed off.

This is the **untrimmed ellipse**

[image: Untrimmed]

This is the **trimmed ellipse**, the goal of this question

[image: Trimmed]

---

### Attempt

**CreateConveyorNameEllipse(AcadDoc)**

```
Public Function CreateConveyorNameEllipse(ByRef AcadDoc As Document) As ObjectId
    Dim returnId As ObjectId
    Dim db As Database = AcadDoc.Database
    Dim x As Vector3d = db.Ucsxdir
    Dim y As Vector3d = db.Ucsydir
    Dim normalVec As Vector3d = x.CrossProduct(y)
    Dim axisvec As Vector3d = normalVec.GetNormal()
    Dim CenterPoint As New Point3d(Me.StartPoint.X + 50, Me.StartPoint.Y + 40, 0)
    Dim aEllipse As Ellipse

    aEllipse = New Ellipse(CenterPoint, axisvec, New Vector3d(30, 0, 0), 0.35, 0, Math.PI * 2)
    aEllipse.SetDatabaseDefaults()
    returnId = Utils.CreateAcadObject(AcadDoc, aEllipse)

    aEllipse.Dispose()
    Utils.regenLayers()

    Return returnId
End Function
```

**CreateConveyorEllipseLineConnection(AcadDoc)**

```
Public Function CreateConveyorEllipseLineConnection(ByRef AcadDoc As Document) As ObjectId
    Dim returnId As ObjectId
    Dim CenterPoint As New Point3d(Me.StartPoint.X + 50, Me.StartPoint.Y + 40, 0)
    Dim aLine As Line

    aLine = New Line(Me.StartPoint, CenterPoint)
    aLine.SetDatabaseDefaults()
    returnId = Utils.CreateAcadObject(AcadDoc, aLine)

    aLine.Dispose()
    Utils.regenLayers()

    Return returnId
End Function
```

**CreateAcadObject(AcadDoc, AcadObj)**

```
Public Function CreateAcadObject(ByRef acDoc As Document, ByRef acObj As Object) As ObjectId
    Dim objId As ObjectId
    Dim acCurDb As Database = acDoc.Database 'Get the current database
    Dim acBlkTbl As BlockTable
    Dim acBlkTblRec As BlockTableRecord

    Using lock As DocumentLock = acDoc.LockDocument
        'Start a transaction
        Using acTrans As Transaction = acCurDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()
            'Open Model space for write
            acBlkTbl = acTrans.GetObject(acCurDb.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead)
            acBlkTblRec = acTrans.GetObject(acBlkTbl(BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace), OpenMode.ForWrite)
            acObj.SetDatabaseDefaults()

            'Add the object to the drawing
            objId = acBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(acObj)
            acTrans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(acObj, True)

            'Commit the changes and dispose of the transaction
            acTrans.Commit()
        End Using
    End Using

    Return objId
End Function
```

---

I'm not quite sure how to apply the trim to the line. I've seen some `IntersectWith` methods but couldn't get it to work yet. I'll be working on this meanwhile and if I find the answer I'll be sure to post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of a few cool methods dealing with curves to handle this:

```
Private Shared Function TrimmedLine(line As Line, ent As Entity) As Line
    If line Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("line")
    End If

    ' Original line is returned since there's nothing to break it
    If ent Is Nothing Then Return line

    Dim extPoints = New Point3dCollection()
    Try
        line.IntersectWith(ent, Intersect.ExtendArgument, extPoints, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)

        ' Original line gets returned since it doesn't intersect
        If extPoints.Count = 0 Then Return line

        Dim splitLines = line.GetSplitCurves(extPoints)

        ' Not sure when this would fail, investigate.
        If splitLines.Count = 0 Then Return Nothing

        ' Return the outer line in this case
        Return DirectCast(splitLines(0), Line)

    Catch ex As Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.Message)
        Throw
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Ha! Once again. You got it. I made some noob mistakes but ended up clearing things up within my code. Thanks a bunch, you saved the day - twice!

Comment: No problem.  I'll always make time for good questions, especially since you've clearly put in effort.

Comment: hi thx for your answer - hi does function edit the existing line passed in (and is it updated in the model space), or does this function merely return a NEW trimmed line, leaving the line extending into the middle of the eclipse unchanged? chrs mate